# Gorilla Mux same endpoint multiple query params

Tags: go, query-string, mux

So I know that **Gorilla Mux** doesn't support optional query params and people suggest to create different routes with query param which makes it more solid. But in my case it is **not resolving the routes as expected**.

If I call `/service/{locale}?param1=1,2&param2=3,4` then it invokes `a.listFirst` while it should call the `a.listSecond` and the same issue with other combinations. But:

1. If I keep only one route then the route works as expected. So I assume the routes itself are fine but there is some resolving issue when they are together?
2. If I remove the first route (the one without query param) and swap the order of the rest then they both work fine. This means the order also matters?

I know I can use `request.URL.Query()` to get the query params but I am curious to know why this way of defining query params as route doesn't work as expected?

```
a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listAll),
    ))

a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Queries("param1", "{param1:[0-9,]+}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listFirst),
    ))

a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Queries("param2", "{param2:[0-9,]+}", "param1", "{param1:[0-9,]+}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listSecond),
    ))
```

I have already looked at these but they dont answer the question [link1](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Queries) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379942/how-to-have-an-optional-query-in-get-request-using-gorilla-mux)

UPDATE

**Short answer:** Order matters

**Tip:** Don't be a fool and use correct handler function

Comment: Routers normally match things in the order they are added, so ordering matters. That means you need to reverse the order of all 3 routes in your code. The most specialized match must come first for things to function properly. This is just an assumption from how routing usually works, as I don't have experience with gorilla mux, but I would be surprised if it didn't follow the same idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order because the order matters. The first match gets selected

```
a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Queries("param2", "{param2:[0-9,]+}", "param1", "{param1:[0-9,]+}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listSecond),
    ))

a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Queries("param1", "{param1:[0-9,]+}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listFirst),
    ))

a.Router.
    Methods(http.MethodGet).
    Path("/service/{locale}").
    Handler(negroni.New(
        a.contentTypeJSON,
        negroni.HandlerFunc(a.listAll),
    ))
```

Comment: You are right order matters and I even tried that because that's how it normally works in other frameworks but heck I was using wrong handler function in my original code which causes the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using grpc-go , grpc-gateway and play around with that, you need not define extra query params this way. everything that is defined in you message can be passed as query params